# "Command not found" discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I am making a discord bot with multiple command but only the one on top seems to work.

```py
import discord
import os
import time
import discord.ext
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions,  CheckFailure, check

client = discord.Client()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$')

count = 0

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready")

@client.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount=100):
  await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
  return

async def hello(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Hi")
           

async def help(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hi")



client.run(("token"))
```

```
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "hello" is not found
```

I would really appreciate it if you could tell me what is wrong.

Comment: You never made a command called `hello`. You made the function, yes, but you didn't attach it to a discord command

Comment: `@client.command()` is missing in the last two cases. Voting to close as typo

Comment: So how do I make it a command @12944qwerty

Comment: You made a command when creating `clear`. Replicate the decorator you used for the other commands as well.

Comment: @client.command is that the decorator?

Comment: Correct, it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no decorator, the function is not registered as a command and therefore cannot be executed, you have to put it every time

```py
@client.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount=100):
  await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
  return

@client.command() # The decorator must be put here
async def hello(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Hi")
           
@client.command() # ... and here too, everytime a function is a command
async def help(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hi")
```